# Visual Studio 2012 Web Express Compile Project with EDMX

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I created a project in Visual Studio 2012 Web Express. After that I included an EDMX file and updated it with database generated models. Now when I perform a build, Visual Studio lists down alot of errors all relating to the piece of code I have written below.

The compiler points the following as errors When I open the Model class. This is the auto generated model class.

```
namespace Mvc
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class MyTableName
    {
        public MyTableName()
        {
```

The moment I move **using** statement outside the namespace as follows, the errors get resolved.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Mvc
{


    public partial class MyTableName
    {
        public MyTableName()
        {
```

I havent faced this issue before and what I performed is simply out of the box. Any clue whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! Looks like the database had a table with a reserved C# class name. Issue Resolved.